# How to Add username/passwords to google chrome(internal) on device using an Flutter application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-chrome, google-cloud-firestore

I have built a flutter application to store, edit and manage username/passwords using google cloud firestore. The user can login through his google account and store his details. **Further, I need to extend it to make the application to store credentials internally in the device such that, when I try to login in another app / browser, The passwords stored in my flutter app shows in the autofill/recommended filed in any textfields outside of the app**. Are there any ways to do like that ?